# asp.net mvc 3 and continuous integration

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I have recently learned about continuous integration. From my understanding, its a way to automatically push code to a test environment once code is checked in. Then, you can eventually easily push that code to a production environment.

Currently, I am using TFS for my source control for an ASP.NET MVC 3 project. My question is, what are the recommendations for continuous integration. Unfortunately, I do not have a budget to actually buy something. With that limitation in mind, what do other devs recommend?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have a chance I'd recommend to replace TFS as a source control system. Use something like Subversion, Git or Mercurial. Continuous integration systems such as TeamCity integrate with any of these. You will also find that with such mainstream tools you are better off. TFS integrates very well with Microsoft tools but less so with non-Mircosoft tools.

Comment: @John how is ASP.NET MVC 3 "non-Microsoft"? the OP does develop in Visual Studio, doesn't he?

Comment: @KMoraz My intention was not so say that ASP.NET MVC 3 is "non-Microsoft". My intention was to say that mainstream specialized tools typically integrate better with other tools in comparison with how TFS integrates. In the end the choice of tools is up to you. In my experience, however, TFS was never a good choice overall in comparison to a toolset that is based on best of breed. I concede that you may have different experiences and in my view that is equally valid.

Comment: @John I understood your view, the thing is it's way off the mark. The question was clearly about which CI is recommended for TFS - directing the OP to another SC is not only irrelevant but also misleading.

Comment: @KMoraz I see and respect your point but disagree. The way I understand the question it is asking for recommendations for continuous integration (CI) for an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and my recommendation for that scenario is to not use team foundation server if possible. There are other options that in my experience are less painful and don't require spending money. If moving away from TFS is not an option then that's the reason why I offered my recommendation as a comment only and not as an answer. I rest my case.

Comment: @John TFS **IS** CI (among other subsystems). It's like recommending a discrete GPS device to someone who own a GPS-enabled smartphone but wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TFS you should be able to do continuous integration with [team foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms364045%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) without the need to buy anything else.

Answer (score 0):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is very popular, and free for up to 20 build configurations.

Version 7 was released last week and includes lots of new features such as NuGet packaging.